# Linq Aggregation Statement To Process Values Null and Not Null Values

Tags: vb.net, linq

I want to add values as Aggregation. But some values are null. The statement gives following error:

> The value for column 'ytd_sales' in table 'titles' is DBNull.

I'm using following statement:

```
Dim AvgCost As Double = Aggregate emp In Me.PublishingWorldDataSet.titles Where (emp.ytd_sales) <> IsDBNull(emp.ytd_sales) Select (emp.ytd_sales) Into Sum()
```

Please help, i'll be thankful.
Thanks

Comment: this question seems not related to c#. please avoid spamming tags

Answer (score 0):

your where clause seems to be wrong have you tried

```
Dim AvgCost As Double = Aggregate emp In Me.PublishingWorldDataSet.titles Where IsDBNull(emp.ytd_sales) = False Select (emp.ytd_sales) Into Sum()
```

if `emp.ytd_sales is null` you are checking if `emp.ytd_sales <> true`